# Magento Checkout Page getting blank Screen?

Tags: php, magento

I am working with a Magento Website, and the checkout page gets just blank. The views are well placed, its just like an error but it doesn't show me any error, it shows nothing.

I am a newbie to Magento so I don't really know how to debug this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you have any plugins? refresh the cache.

Comment: Improved the Text Formatting and added a clear Question Title.

Comment: Check your system and exception logs, and if there's nothing in them then check your web server and/or PHP error logs. There'll be something in there that will tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: uncomment this line in index.php file present in root of the site : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` and check what error is displaying in chekcout ?  [link](http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/magento-solved-internal-server-error-500-error/)